# Azure AD B2C - Disable/Block Sign-in for Social/Federated Users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I apologize if this has been asked in the past. The last post (I found) here and on UserVoice asking this question was in 2017 so I wanted to be sure nothing has changed since then.
I am able to disable/block local accounts in B2C via Graph by setting AccountEnabled to false. The message when the user tries to sign in is "Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again." Please correct me if that is not how to go about it. However, the same doesn't seem to work for federated accounts.

How can one disable/block sign-in for a federated/social account?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because those are always disabled, and the check is skipped since that check occurs when B2C checks the backend for creds.

Use this sample
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-social-account-from-logon

Comment: Thanks @Jas! What options do i have as fa as hiding the dummy textbox? HTML/CSS?

Comment: Yes, customise the block page with CSS. Make sure at least one outputclaim is provided on the block page and it must have required=true set on the claim.

Comment: How should the "extension_accountEnabled" attribute be handled? I'm probably missing something, but I do not see how/where it does get set, so I'm assuming one should use powershell or a call to GraphAPI to set it.

My issue is that I'm doing that, I do not see any change in the sample behavior...

Comment: You need to set the attribute with powershell/graph api. Make sure you target the extension attribute and not the native accountEnabled attribute.

Comment: Thanks @JasSuri-MSFT ! I've managed to make it work, once I realized that the extension property name was wrong. I had to add the app id to the name like "extension_<app id>_accountEnabled.
Not sure why, but it got that name even creating it on the portal.

Comment: Jas, want to let you know that this community is greater with you in it!

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT why is the "dummy" claim needed as an output? It happens to show the user a new page with input fields and buttons after calling "AAD-DisabledUserPage". I wonder why is that necessary as I'd expect the error message right away from the claims transformation defined on "AAD-AssertAccountEnabled".